# loading url with ajax and jquery for each item

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If I am using ajax and jquery to view something from database , this will happen behind the scenes . Alright ? but If I want to use ajax,jquery and make changes in the url . How can that happen ? 
For example : I am viewing news in the site ,,how can I make a unique url for each news to be accessed or shared by the user,,although it is working behind the scenes ?

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#see',function(){
        var ID = $("#rowid").val();
        var er = "_|_";

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'news.php',
            data:'var='+ID,
            success:function(response){  
        //     history.pushState('data', '', 'news.php?var='+ID);
             window.location.href = "news.php?var="+ID;   
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

php

```
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>

<?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("../icac/includes/db-connect.php");
 mysqli_query($con,"set names 'utf8'");
$query="SELECT * FROM `icac_content_tbl` LIMIT 1";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

<h1><input id="rowid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["content_title"]; ?>"/></h1>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="see">see link</a>
<h2><?php    if( $row["content_title"] == $_GET["var"]) { echo $row["content_title"];

    echo "<br>"; echo $row["content_body"];
    ;}  ?></h2>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: any answers plz ??

Comment: can you show us what have done or some jsfiddle ?

Comment: okk  I will update my question

Comment: @Sudarpo Chong  please check

Comment: And what is ur objective? I'm having hard time understanding what you want to do?
can you write in more detail?

Comment: for ex: news.php displays news ...I want a button or  <a href> called see link   . When the user clicks see link , it will show the news in a unique link like news.php?id=1001 ...but I need this to be in ajax and jquery not pure php

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/rhfm3yne/1/
is this what you want ?